# Bootstrap fill table from json_encode php function

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, pdo

I'm trying to populate my bootstrap table from a php function and i can't get this to work and the strange is the function Works since i have result in my console log but the table is not populate.
This is the code

```
<table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-striped"
               data-toggle="table"
               data-pagination="true"
               data-search="true"
               data-show-refresh="true"
               data-show-toggle="true"
               data-show-columns="true"
               data-toolbar="#toolbar"
               data-url='<?php $user->getAllItems(); ?>'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="id_itens" class="hidden">ID</th>
                    <th data-field="nome" data-editable="true" class="alinhado">Nome</th>
                    <th data-field="descricao" data-editable="true" class="alinhado">Descrição</th>
                    <th data-field="tipo" data-editable="true" class="alinhado">Tipo</th>
                    <th data-field="estado" data-editable="true" class="alinhado">Descrição</th>
                    <th data-field="data" data-editable="true" class="alinhado">Data</th>
                    <th data-field="quantidade" data-editable="true" class="alinhado">Quantidade</th>
                    <th data-field="operate" data-formatter="operateFormatter" data-events="operateEvents" class="alinhado">Opções</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

and this is my php fucntion

```
public function getAllItems(){
    try{
        $sql = "SELECT `id_itens`, `nome`, `descricao`, `data`, `quantidade`, `tipo`, `estado` FROM `item`
        INNER JOIN `item_estado` ON (`item`.`id_estado` = `item_estado`.`id_estado`)
        INNER JOIN `tipo_item` ON (`item`.`id_tipo` = `tipo_item`.`id_tipo`)";
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $itens = array();
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $itens[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($itens);
    }catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

If i create a separate file without function just using that code, it Works, i mean instead of calling a function i call a php file ex: xxx.php

```
    try{
$sql = "SELECT `id_itens`, `nome`, `descricao`, `data`, `quantidade`, `tipo`, `estado` FROM `item`
INNER JOIN `item_estado` ON (`item`.`id_estado` = `item_estado`.`id_estado`)
INNER JOIN `tipo_item` ON (`item`.`id_tipo` = `tipo_item`.`id_tipo`)";
$query = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$itens = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $itens[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($itens);
}catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

So anyone can explain me it doesn't work with function?

Thanks

Comment: How does `$this->db` get defined?

Comment: Also, the whole `foreach` thing is not needed.  Just encode `$result` after the fetch.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help: private $db;
    function __construct($DB_con) {
        $this->db = $DB_con;
    }

Comment: i get this error in my console: http://xxxxxxx/xxxxx/[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20…%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object]?order=asc&limit=10&offset=0 404 - jquery.min.js

Comment: This error?!?! What error?

Comment: Is the user class available at the time of the call? might want to echo out some of the lines and see where the problem lies - maybe theres an error in your log but not on screen.

Comment: yes Testani, it is, in my console i have this in ex: <table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-striped"
data-url='[{"id_itens":"2","nome":"Aplica\u00e7\u00f5es Inform\u00e1ticas e Sistemas de Explora\u00e7\u00e3o","descricao":"M\u00f3dulos 4, 5 e 6 - N\u00edvel 3 ","data":"2015-09-25","quantidade":"20"

Comment: So instead of putting the json result in the table i have the result in data-url

Comment: if someone want to check it live this is the url : http://esmaior.pt/biblioteca/getItems.php

Comment: Im not sure what the problem is, it's outputting JSON, am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, it is output Json, but the problem is that Json is not in my table like should be.